# Путь в функции move_uploaded_file

Tags: php

Почему этот код работает
    $dest_url = get_home_path() . "imagebase/1/" . $new_image_file;

```
      if (move_uploaded_file($new_image_file_tmp, $dest_url)) {
        //сделать что-то
      }
```

а этот нет(название сайта изменил)

```
$dest_url = "https://example.com/imagebase/1/" . $new_image_file;

      if (move_uploaded_file($new_image_file_tmp, $dest_url)) {
        //сделать что-то
      }
```

ошибка - failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections

Comment: Не работает потому что `get_home_path()` возвращает абсолютный путь к файлу на сервере (к папке где WP сам лежит).. Некий аналог `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо использовать `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` для получения корня сервера (где файлы сайта лежат), поскольку обращение через твой пример может не быть переадресовано как надо.